# How do I change the scale and coordinates of the visualViewport?

Tags: javascript, html, viewport, pinchzoom

I want to change the scale and coordinates of `visualViewport` but all of the properties for that interface seem to be read-only.

Is there a way I can change the visualViewport scale and coordinates?

I tried to edit the properties of the `visualViewport` interface but they're read-only. I also tried looking up ways to edit the `visualViewport` but couldn't find anything.

Comment: That’s because you cannot change what device your user is using. You CAN change your meta-viewport tag though!

Comment: @Kokodoko How would I change that programmatically?

Comment: It's not recommended to change the `meta viewport` tag while your application is running. But perhaps you could include your actual problem in your code, otherwise it's a bit hard to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Kokodoko There isn't really any code in particular. I have the webpage as a webview inside an app. I want the webpage to load with the viewport zoomed in on a particular location.
The visualViewport interface lets me track viewport changes but I want to make changes to the viewport - I just need to change the viewport on webpage load but ideally I'd like to change the viewport whenever.